# ATLASSUME assertion fails in CDialogImpl::EndDialog(IDCLOSE)

Tags: windows, visual-c++, atl, assertion

I'm calling `EndDialog(IDCLOSE)` to end the application in a class inheriting `CDialogImpl` and I get a Debug Assertion Failed run time error on `ATLASSUME(m_bModal)` in `CDialogImpl::EndDialog(int)`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You typically post `WM_CLOSE` to "end" a modeless window: [Closing the Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, `PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT)` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EndDialog` is meant to close a **modal** dialog and [should not be used for a dialog-based application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aka1xc8.aspx). To terminate an application call [`CWindow::DestroyWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53z8e416.aspx) instead.

This is one of the places where the encapsulation breaks and the implementation exposes implementation details to the user. `EndDialog` performs additional operations on top of destroying the dialog window. The additional work (like storing the return value) is meaningless for a dialog-based application. The result is that you have to call different methods to terminate a dialog depending on context.

Comment: I don't understand why, but `DestroyWindow` breaks in another debug assertion fail, this time at `ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd))` in `ATL::CWindow::SetWindowTextW(const wchar_t * lpszString)`. It did, however, work with `PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT)`.

Comment: @theDane I may have misinterpreted your question. I was under the impression that you have a dialog-based application (i.e. the application GUI consists of a single dialog) which you are trying to terminate. Reading the question again it sounds like you are trying to terminate an application from a dialog. It would probably help if you could update the question with the specifics and provide relevant source code. In the meantime do not accept this as an answer - it might not address your specific problem.